# AST parser datatype problems in scala

Tags: parsing, scala, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is my code: http://pastie.org/private/t37ectjdnplit66zidj6hq

This code is for a pascal-like language parser. I have a problem in these lines : 178 , 181, 193. When I have a defined grammar with the keyword : [Any], I run it successfully ! but when I replace that keyword by one of  traits and "case classes" , it notifies me have a mistake ! I think I don't understand the meanings when use the code : parser[???]. Can anybody help me to resolve these problems?

```
line 181: def val_type : Parser[Type] = primitive| array_type | string_type

line 193: def ident_list  : Parser[List[Id]] = ident ~(rep(","~> ident))
```

Updated:
Here are the corresponding errors:

```
line 181: type mismatch;  found   : MPRecognizer.this.Parser[Any]  required:   MPRecognizer.this.Parser[Type]
line 193: type mismatch;  found   : MPRecognizer.this.Parser[MPRecognizer.this.~[String,List[String]]]  required: MPRecognizer.this.Parser[Id]
```

Comment: Any is not a keyword, it is a type. Thus, I do not understand what you want to do with a `trait` or a `case class`, could you explain this further? And please post full error messages otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: this is my ideas !
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?dfi3btvtaj20qag

Comment: In first week, I create a defined grammar with no trait and case classes to complete phase 1 and phase 2 in my duty!Now I got a trouble with phase 3 ! If you can help ,please read this file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?mkf1u7a3x7mqauz

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the original code, not the one you modified by making everything return `Parser[Any]`.

The error messages tell you that not all alternatives produce an instance of `Type`. For example, check that the methods `primitive`, `array_type` and `string_type` all return a `Parser[Type]`. Add the type annotation to each of them, and if you get type errors in the modified definitions, narrow it down further in the same way.